# Can't hear any sounds from MIDI

Tags: java, midi

i'm starting with java, and tryin' to play some sounds using midi. I'm following the "Head First" book. The problem is i can't hear any sound, here's my code

```
package pakedz;
import javax.sound.midi.*;

public class odtwarzaczMuzyki {
  public void graj(){
   try {
    Sequencer sekwenser = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
    System.out.println("Mamy sekwenser");
    sekwenser.open();

    Sequence sekwencja = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ,4);
    Track sciezka = sekwencja.createTrack();

    ShortMessage a = new ShortMessage();
    a.setMessage(144, 1, 20, 100);
    MidiEvent nutaP = new MidiEvent(a, 1);
    sciezka.add(nutaP);
    ShortMessage b = new ShortMessage();
    b.setMessage(128, 1, 44, 100);
    MidiEvent nutaK = new MidiEvent(b, 16);
    sciezka.add(nutaK);

     sekwenser.setSequence(sekwencja);

 } catch (Exception ex) { 
    System.out.println("KUTASMARIAN");
}

 };

 public static void main (String[] args){
 odtwarzaczMuzyki radio = new odtwarzaczMuzyki();
 radio.graj();

 }

}
```

i'm using java 8.0

Comment: Are your speakers plugged in?

Comment: Ok so what does debugging your code tell you?

Comment: If you could tell me what do you exatly mean? I have no errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to call the `start()` method in Sequencer.  Below is the modified (untested) code.

Recommend checking the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/midi/Sequencer.html) and [official tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/MIDI-seq-methods.html).

```
package pakedz;
import javax.sound.midi.*;

public class odtwarzaczMuzyki {
  public void graj(){
    try {
      Sequencer sekwenser = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
      System.out.println("Mamy sekwenser");
      sekwenser.open();

      Sequence sekwencja = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ,4);
      Track sciezka = sekwencja.createTrack();

      ShortMessage a = new ShortMessage();
      a.setMessage(144, 1, 20, 100);
      MidiEvent nutaP = new MidiEvent(a, 1);
      sciezka.add(nutaP);
      ShortMessage b = new ShortMessage();
      b.setMessage(128, 1, 44, 100);
      MidiEvent nutaK = new MidiEvent(b, 16);
      sciezka.add(nutaK);

      sekwenser.setSequence(sekwencja);
      sekwenser.start();

    }
    catch (Exception ex) { 
      System.out.println("KUTASMARIAN");
    }
  };

  public static void main (String[] args) {
    odtwarzaczMuzyki radio = new odtwarzaczMuzyki();
    radio.graj();
  }
}
```